# Creating a button on a from using a button from a different form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, button, panel

Is there any way to create a button on a form using a button from a different form? Here's what I have tried so far and nothing is showing up on the other form:

```
            Homepage homepage = new Homepage();

            Button NewClassroom = new Button();
            NewClassroom.Text = txtCreateCName.Text;
            NewClassroom.Name = txtCreateCID.Text;
            NewClassroom.Size = new Size(330, 55);
            NewClassroom.Location = new Point(0,3);

            homepage.panel3.Controls.Add(NewClassroom);
            NewClassroom.BringToFront();
```

Comment: *In the other Form*, makes one think that this Form is already shown, so `Homepage homepage = new Homepage();` creates a **new Instance** of that class, unrelated to the existing, hence nothing will be added to the **existing Instance**. -- `Panel3` access modifier **should not** be `public`. -- Add instead a public method to `Homepage` that accepts a Control as argument and then adds (on its own terms) this new Control to the collection of Controls of an internal UI element.

Answer (score 0):

At the running stage, it is hard to create a new Control and populate it with properties and event handlers. Instead of creating a new button in click handler, **I would suggest creating a hidden button when the other form is in design**. Then you can click the button and make it visible.

So in the event of the button click, a new statement like this is needed:

> btnNewClassroom.Visible = true

Besides, microsoft Docs is a good place to learn dotnet programming and I like it. Here is a topic about it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/add-controls-to-windows-forms

Comment: Of course at run-time you can create new Controls. -- *When a winform application runs, it is running in CLR where the Button Control is not supported* doesn't mean anything and *Buttons* (any Control) is of course *supported* in this platform. -- You can create and use any kind of Controls at run-time, provided that you do it the right way (in this case, considering the Form's Instance where the new Control should be added to).